# Why does this Angular 6 onclick function not working properly?

Tags: javascript, binding, angular6, buttonclick

So, I built a quick Angular 6 app to help estimate bill amounts given the start and end date of the period a user wants to calculate for. (ex. 1 and 5 would return the total amount of bills from the 1st to the 5th).

Anyways, I have a button run the following function when clicked (this.bills$ is the json data im using) but its not working when i enter a startDay higher than the endDay.

```js
  estimateBills() {
    this.estimateText = 0;


    console.log('00: startDay is: ' + this.startDay + ' and, endDay is: ' + this.endDay);


    if (this.startDay < this.endDay) {
      console.log('1: startDay is: ' + this.startDay + ' and, endDay is: ' + this.endDay);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.bills$.length; i++) {
        if (this.startDay <= this.bills$[i].DueDate && this.endDay >= this.bills$[i].DueDate) {
          console.log('Bill DueDate is: ' + this.bills$[i].DueDate + ' and Amount is ' + this.bills$[i].Amount);
          this.estimateText = +this.estimateText + this.bills$[i].Amount;
        }
      }
    }
    else if (this.startDay > this.endDay) {
      console.log('2: startDay is: ' + this.startDay + ' and, endDay is: ' + this.endDay);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.bills$.length; i++) {
        console.log('looping');
        if (this.startDay <= this.bills$[i].DueDate || this.endDay >= this.bills$[i].DueDate) {
          console.log('Bill DueDate is: ' + this.bills$[i].DueDate + ' and Amount is ' + this.bills$[i].Amount);
          this.estimateText = +this.estimateText + this.bills$[i].Amount;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      this.estimateText = 1;
    }


  }
```

Here are some examples of what i get when run the function. For some reason it does not realize that the startDay is higher than the endDay! idk what is going wrong

[When startDay is smaller than endDay (correct output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Srd.png)

[When endDay is smaller than startDay (incorrect output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29qZ9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the reason is that both `this.startDay` and `this.endDay` are strings, therefore `"28" < "4"` comparison is `true` (first characters '2' and '4' are compared in this case).

Explicit cast to numbers may help here, i.e. `Number(this.startDay) < Number(this.endDay)`.

Comment: Wow, I cant believe I didnt see that. So simple lol. Thank you!